# flask Where to place code to ping elasticsearch

Tags: python, multithreading, elasticsearch, flask

I use elasticsearch in my app. Since I also use blueprints, `create_app` is defined in the app's `__init__.py`, which is where `app.elasticsearch` is initialized.

When elasticsearch.ping() fails, I'd like to send an email to an address. I can't send the email in `init.py` as I need to import email function from another file that is also dependent on `app`. (cyclic)

I'm doing the ping and check at the views, and it feels very wrong as the check has to be performed every visit on the associated page. **Where should I place the elasticsearch.ping and email bit?**

```
def ping_elasticsearch(app):
    with app.app_context():
        if not app.elasticsearch.ping():
            app.elasticsearch = None
            send_email('[Microblog] Elasticsearch server cannot be reached',
                       sender=app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'],
                       recipients=[app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER']],
                       text_body='Elasticsearch server cannot be reached.',
                       html_body='Elasticsearch server cannot be reached.')


@bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@bp.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    if not current_app.elasticsearch_pinged:
        if current_app.elasticsearch:
            Thread(target=ping_elasticsearch, args=[current_app._get_current_object()]).start()
        current_app.elasticsearch_pinged = True
        ...
```

**EDIT:**

I want app/__init__.py to look like this (note elasticsearch):

```
...
def ping_elasticsearch(app):
    with app.app_context():
        if not app.elasticsearch.ping():
            app.elasticsearch = None
            send_email('[Microblog] Elasticsearch server cannot be reached',
                       sender=app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'],
                       recipients=[app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER']],
                       text_body='Elasticsearch server cannot be reached.',
                       html_body='Elasticsearch server cannot be reached.')

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    login.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    moment.init_app(app)
    babel.init_app(app)
    app.elasticsearch = Elasticsearch([app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL']], timeout=10) \
        if app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] else None
    app.elasticsearch_pinged = False
    if app.elasticsearch:
        Thread(target=ping_elasticsearch, args=[current_app._get_current_object()]).start()

    from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)
    ...
```

and the `email.py` module has the following code:

```
from threading import Thread
from flask import current_app
from flask_mail import Message
from app import mail


def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)


def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    Thread(target=send_async_email,
           args=(app, msg)).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't import 'app' from **init**.py in the file which you have email function instead import with folder name so whereever you are referring the app you can write it as fol_name.app. this will avoid cyclic import

eg. folder name is 'src' and your in your email file write like this

```
import src
def some_func():
   app = src.app
```